# Zona Horaria de Otro Pais - SQL Server

Tags: sql, tsql, transact-sql

*Hola
Actualmente en mi empresa tenemos un sistema el cual el servidor se encuentra en Miami

por lo que cuando se registra una transacción , la hora que sale es la de Miami, por ejemplo:

Si en honduras se realiza una transacción o cualquier registro a las `09:00 am`, en la base se guarda como `11:00 am`, por la diferencia de 2 horas que hay entre Honduras-Miami

Lo he solucionado temporalmente colocándole un `DATEDIFF` y restándole 2 horas manualmente, para asi obtener la hora correcta, sin embargo, con los cambios de horarios que hay en USA

Existira alguna forma o alguna funcion de SQL Server, que capture la Zona horaria de MIAMI para asi ver cual es la diferencia entre esa zona horaria de MIAMI y HONDURAS y colocar la hora correcta?

Comment: El tema de fechas, se recomienda grabarlas en UTC +0 y hacer la conversión del lado del cliente.

Comment: Me imagino que es algún campo `datetime` que coge la hora a la que se inserta el dato. Porque no, en lugar de hacerlo con SQL, lo envías desde el Lenguaje que tiene el aplicativo con el tiempo de HN?? Bastaría con mandarle un `now()` a ese campo. Aunque tu pides con SQL, pero es una opción... PD: el `now()` es de PHP, tu lo podrías hacer con la función que te brinde tu lenguaje.

Comment: Es correcto es un campo Datetime, sin embargo debo de hacerlo desde SQL

Comment: Sql server tiene muchas funciones para el manejo de fechas y desplazamientos. El tema es más complicado de lo que parece. No obstante si tu Servidor es Sql Server 2016 o superior, puedes usar de una manera muy simple [At Time Zone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)